# Facebook PHP SDK to comment on Post

Tags: facebook

Dear I want to make comment on my posts using Graph API.
At present I am doing this in localhost. I am able to get Login button and deal with that.

From FB, I've copied this code. Now I want to make a test comment but it prompts this error:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in F:\wamp\www\FunnyNLol\facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev\src\basic.php on line 43 and defined in F:\wamp\www\FunnyNLol\facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev\src\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 182

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0

require_once '../autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'XXXXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXXXX');

// login helper with redirect_uri

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://mydomaincom/tag/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/1793370944220599/comments',
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test comment',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
?>
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0) part of the SDK tutorial as well. In order to do those graph API calls you need to create a Facebook Session via their login helper.

Hence, the error output you're sessing related to the `$session` variable that you are passing into the FacebookRequest constructor and aren't initializing anywhere.

Comment: I added this code as you suggested                                                         $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://mydomaincom/tag/' );
 
 try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

Comment: I am getting this error                                                                     Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given

Comment: Okay, well you're going to need to sort it out from there. You have to use that FacebookRedirectLoginHelper class to redirect whoever you are pulling graph data on behalf of to login with Facebook. Once that works, the `$session` variable will be populated and that error should go away.

Comment: var_dump( $session );  returns NULL. This is my login and my App ID and App Secret.